# Using Apache as a reverse proxy for AWS S3 bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, http, amazon-s3

I have been stuck on this issue for a bit and was wondering if maybe I could get any pointers in the right direction. :))

I have an AWS S3 bucket that I would like to put behind an Apache web server.

I'm testing locally using a httpd Docker image.

I have an S3 bucket with a folder named "folder" and a file inside that folder named "file.txt" and also "file.zip"

I want the URI requests to my Apache web server for "/file.txt" or "/file.zip" to proxy over to my S3 bucket so the file is downloaded.

Current **httpd-custom.conf** (I've tried different variations)

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    <LocationMatch "/file(.*)(.zip|.txt)">
        ProxyPass https://<bucket name>.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/$1
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Current **S3 bucket policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "S3_Policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyNonProxyWebAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/folder/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "<IP of host where I am running the httpd docker image>/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Current **S3 bucket CORS config**:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

Also, S3 bucket is set to be public. It seems I have it working partially, however the files don't download. A directory content-type is returned instead.

```
# Direct Curl to S3 bucket
→  curl -I https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/file.txt
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: <>
x-amz-request-id: <>
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2020 20:19:37 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 15:19:07 GMT
ETag: "<>"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 17277
Server: AmazonS3

# Direct Curl to Apache
→  curl -I http://localhost:9898/file.txt
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2020 20:20:48 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: <>
x-amz-request-id: <>
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 15:18:06 GMT
ETag: "<>"
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/x-directory

# Apache Log
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2020:20:20:49 +0000] "HEAD /updateSupport.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I've also tried the following config to no avail. I either run into the "application/x-directory" content-type or a 403 error.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost
    <LocationMatch "/file(.*)(.zip|.txt)">
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        ProxyPass https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/$1
        ProxyPassReverse https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/$1
        RequestHeader set "Host" "<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com"
        RequestHeader unset Cookie
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

At this point, I'm lost. Not sure if I am making a simple mistake or if it has something to do with the Docker image/setup.

Apache Version / Modules:

```
root@a168a8c4866c:/usr/local/apache2# httpd -M
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 proxy_http2_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
root@a168a8c4866c:/usr/local/apache2# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix)
Server built:   Jun  9 2020 07:00:39
```

Comment: Could it be that the re-write engine is only matching the ".txt" or ".zip" part of the file? In that case, you need to modify the proxypass statement to: ProxyPass https://<bucket name>.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/file$1. Might also be a good idea to enable s3 data events in CloudTrail for this bucket. Turn it off when done debugging.

Comment: @petern, thank you that was helpful. I enabled static S3 hosting on the bucket and instead of using the "$1" I hard-coded the values in the proxypass path and I'm able to get the files. Any idea how I can pass the "file.txt" or "file123.zip" from the locationmatch regex to the proxy pass line? I was under the assumption that $1 would pass the URI matched.

Comment: I'd try something in the lines of /(file(.*)(.txt|.zip)), that way the match covers everything after "/". Didn't test that, but here's the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch